# Cannot save another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")` to a new workbook.
The file name should be `sheet2.Cells(1, 1)` .

And i have defined the worksheet save location and filename .

Now , I can copy `worksheet-report` to a new workbook .However , that file name is 1,2,3,......  (not my expected file name `sheet2.Cells(1, 1)` .
Also the file hasn't been saved . If i close the new workbook , it asks me to save. And i go to that folder ,i cant find that workbook .

What's the matter? (it should saved in that folder and named well .)

```
  Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        wb.SaveAs "R:\Summer \eva\" & sheet2.Cells(1, 1) & ".xlsx"
```

## update

even i use `thisworkbook.worksheets("report")` not working

cells(1,"A") is a combined cells ,that combines A1 to V1

i tried cells(6,"a") .it is "111" .it works .It can save and name correctly

## 2 update

I tried to paste cells(1,1) into one single cell .It is still not working .
Then i try to shorten my sentence from 8 words to 3 words .It works.
Is it about the file name words limit ?

## 3 update

i paste cells(1,1) -7 words to another cells and test again .It is working .
i think it is not related to the cell length . 
I guess the reason here :

cells(1,1) is combined by:

```
   If (fromyear = toyear And frommonth = ToMonth) Then
[A1].Value = "Management statistics on abc work for " & fromyear & "/" & frommonth
Else
[A1].Value = "Management statistics on abc work" & " from " & fromyear & "/" & frommonth & " to " & toyear & "/" & ToMonth
End If
```

But i have no idea how to solve .

Comment: Is `sheet2` in `wb` or the workbook you are copying from (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`). You don't specify this in you `SaveAs` argument.

Comment: @ Robin Mackenzie from thisworkbook even i use`thisworkbook.worksheets("report") not working

Comment: So `sheet2` is the same as `Sheets("report")`?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie yes

Comment: `strFileName = "R:\Summer\eva\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report").Cells(1, 1).Value & ".xlsx"` then do `wb.SaveAs strFileName`.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie  cells(1,"A") is a combined cells ,that combines A1 to V1 Is it the reason ? So ,i cant fetch cells(1,"a") ?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie not working ,even i paste the value of A1 to another cells to test . It is still not working